# Expected System.String, got System.Guid

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, guid, s#arp-architecture

I am hoping there is a very simple explanation why I am getting this error.

I am using S#arpArcitecture 1.6. on a 64bit Windows 7 install.

Line 3 of the following code gives the error:

*{"Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: System.String, got System.Guid"}    System.Exception {NHibernate.TypeMismatchException}*

```
1 public Category GetCategory(Guid id)
2    {
3        Category cat = categoryRepository.Get(id);
4        return cat;
5    }
```

*Supporting Info*

**Table (SQL Server 2008)**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MasterCategories] (
    [masterCategoryId] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [organizationId] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [categoryNumber] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL
)
```

**Entity Definition**

```
public class Category : EntityWithTypedId<Guid>
```

**Fluent Mapping**

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Category> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("MasterCategories");

        mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("masterCategoryId");
        mapping.Map(x => x.Number).Column("categoryNumber");

        mapping.References(x => x.Organization)
            .Column("organizationId")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
```

**Repository Interface**

```
public interface ICategoryRepository : IRepositoryWithTypedId<Category,Guid>
{
}
```

**Repository**

```
public class CategoryRepository : 
             RepositoryWithTypedId<Category,Guid>, 
             ICategoryRepository
{ }
```

Comment: Can you get the xml generated by Fluent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mapping needs to be like this:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Category> mapping)
{
    mapping.Table("MasterCategories");
    mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("masterCategoryId").GeneratedBy.Guid();
    mapping.Map(x => x.Number).Column("categoryNumber");

    mapping.References(x => x.Organization)
            .Column("organizationId")
            .Cascade.All();
}
```

Comment: Chris, thanks for the answer, but only changing generatedBy to Guid does not seem to affect how the type is passed to NHibernate.  When I change the identity type to string in all the appropriate places, the Get command works.

I am now working on saving which will need to have GenerateBy set.